# No response from celery worker with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, celery

I am trying to use tensorflow in a celery worker. I encountered timeout rather than receiving response from the worker.

I used following code:

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_init

import tensorflow as tf

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

class TFModel():
  def __init__(self):
    self.sess = tf.Session()
  def run(self):
    return self.sess.run(tf.constant('hello'))

tf_model = None

@worker_init.connect
def on_worker_init(**_):
  global tf_model
  tf_model = TFModel()
  print(tf_model.run())
  return

@app.task(time_limit=10)
def run():
  return tf_model.run()
```

test.py

```
import time
from tasks import run

r=run.delay()
while not r.ready():
  time.sleep(2)

print(r.get())
```

I executed a worker with this command.

`$ celery -A tasks worker -l info -c 1`

When I executed the worker, `hello` was printed out, since `on_worker_init()` had `print(tf_model.run())`.
This means that tensorflow works properly.

Then, I ran:

`$ python test.py`

Then, I got:

`celery.backends.base.TimeLimitExceeded: TimeLimitExceeded(10,)`

What was wrong?
How can I investigate what happened?

My environment is:

```
python 3.5.1
tensorflow 0.11.0
celery 4.0.2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.signals import worker_init, worker_process_init
from models import Network, Extractor
from celery.concurrency import asynpool
asynpool.PROC_ALIVE_TIMEOUT = 100.0 #set this long enough

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/'

# Celery: Distributed Task Queue
app = Celery('tasks', backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)
app.conf.task_serializer   = 'json'
app.conf.result_serializer = 'json'

tf_model = None

@worker_process_init.connect()
def on_worker_init(**_):
  global tf_model
  # Create server with model
  logger.info('model for worker: started init')
  print("model for dsa")
  session = tf.Session()
  model = Network(session, True)
  #model.load_model('./models/test_2')
  extractor = Extractor(model)
  tf_model = extractor
  logger.info('model for worker: initialized')


@app.task(name='process_single')
def process_single(image):
    logger.info('process_single: started')
    descriptor = tf_model.process_single(image)
    logger.info('process_single: completed')

    return descriptor
```

It looks for me that this is working:

```
[2017-01-21 09:41:18,892: INFO/Worker-1] ???[???]: model for worker: started init
[2017-01-21 09:41:18,893: WARNING/Worker-1] model for dsa
[2017-01-21 09:41:18,902: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2017-01-21 09:41:18,915: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-01-21 09:41:19,920: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-01-21 09:41:19,949: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@cospelpc ready.
[2017-01-21 09:41:20,930: INFO/Worker-1] ???[???]: model for worker: initialized
[2017-01-21 09:41:31,648: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: process_single[024068ba-9ea2-4405-8aab-d3504a06aa55]
[2017-01-21 09:41:31,658: INFO/Worker-1] process_single[024068ba-9ea2-4405-8aab-d3504a06aa55]: process_single: started
[2017-01-21 09:41:33,125: INFO/Worker-1] process_single[024068ba-9ea2-4405-8aab-d3504a06aa55]: process_single: completed
[2017-01-21 09:41:33,128: INFO/MainProcess] Task process_single[024068ba-9ea2-4405-8aab-d3504a06aa55] succeeded in 1.470330449s: [153608.4375, 0.0, 0.0, 243285.75, 0.0, 155679.671875, 346120.625, 70663.265625, 0.0, 29445.03125, 0.0, 518396.25, 0.0,...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you use keras? I am wondering why sess.run() does not work with celery.

Comment: I am using tensorflow directly so no keras, initialization of network is done in constructor. Using session.run with no problem in tf_model.process_single.

Comment: Be aware that i am using @worker_process_init.connect() and not @worker_init. Also try to do some print/logging so you can see if your model is loaded properly.